# When im using android Onclick("onClick") App showing that your App is stopped

Tags: webview

I've create a app using webview so now i want to add a bottom nav so i've create a bottom_nav.xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
     <item

            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Home"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            tools:ignor="onClick"
            />
        <item

            android:id="@+id/nav_category"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_categories"
            android:title="Categories"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            tools:ignor="onClick"
            />
        <item

            android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_cart"
            android:title="Cart"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            tools:ignor="onClick"
            />
        <item

            android:id="@+id/nav_acount"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_acount"
            android:title="Acount"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            tools:ignor="onClick"

            />


</menu>
```

& Then added these code in mainactivity xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
```

So when I run the app it shows that your application has been stoped !

[image]

& when i remove

```
<android:onClick="onClick/>
```

from bottomnav xml its running fine & shows the navbar icon correctly!

Also I cant find the `<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView/>`
`
Note: im Not a Java pro coder!

Thanks for your time

Comment: otherwise plz tell me a way to create a bottom navbar with 4 icon these icons will linked to 4 pages as i've mentioned its webview app.

Answer (score 0):

Menu items cant be linked with onclick in xml. You have to create an override method which gets the id of the item when user clicks on it and then that id can be compared with if statements. Check the method here

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

// COMPARE THE IDs OF YOUR ITEMS USING THE IF STATEMENTS

      if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            //DO YOUR ONCLICK HERE
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_category) {
            //DO YOUR ONCLICK HERE
        }
if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
            //DO YOUR ONCLICK HERE
        }
if (id == R.id.nav_acount) {
            //DO YOUR ONCLICK HERE
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

EDIT : Refer to some youtube videos for better understanding. It will be hard if you dont learn before implementing things.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh4YOj9VkVE

Comment: so do i need to remove the click property & where & how to use these code you've given ? Thanks Dharman :-)

Comment: This is an override method. If you are using android studio, when you press ctrl + O, you will be able to see all the override methods available. Remove all the onclick property from xml. Now move to the java class of the activity which contains this menu. There, within the class you can add this code below the Oncreate or anywhere. Assuming you are new, do not add this code inside any function. It should be placed outside the functions but inside the class. For your ease, add it above the last `}`. Change the ids for your items.

Comment: I have made changes to my anwser. Please check